# Creating a continuous counter with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
function lemath()
{
    var count;
    count = 0;
    stuff.innerHTML = "stuff" + count;

}

function begin()
{
    lemath();
    setTimeout(function() {
        begin();
    }, 1000);

}
```

I'm trying to create an infinite loop that will count each time it loops and display it, but when I do the code above it just gives back undefined?
Thank you very much with the help! :)

Comment: Where is `stuff` defined ? `count` appear to be reset to `0` at each call to `lemath` ?

Comment: stuff is just the name of the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var count = 0; // declaring "count" here makes the variable globally available

function lemath()
{    
    count++;
    var stuff = document.getElementById('stuff');
    stuff.innerHTML = "stuff: " + count;
}

function begin()
{
    lemath();
    setTimeout(begin, 1000, window);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {    
    begin();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pottersky/jj30s2Le/1/

Comment: Oh my god thank you, I've been struggling with this for past 3 hours!

Answer (score 0):

#### you can use `setInterval` javascript method for increase your counter

```js
// setInterval(fn, time);

 // your counter state should be start from 0
let count = 0;

// Your function should be run each time (for example each second)
const increment = () => {
    count++
// show count in console or in DOM
    console.log(count)
    element.innerHTML = count
}

setInterval(increment, 1000);
```

#### For Performance reason and for stop or reset timer you can use `clearInterval` method

```js
const timer = setInterval(increment, 1000);

 // stop counter

  clearInterval(timer)
```